# calculator , printing a decimal

Tags: java, android

im working on a calculator using android studio. Im having a really hard time trying to get my decimal button to work right. I have no idea how to get it to print a decimal to the screen. this is what i have below , which doesnt work.

```
private void deciDisplay(int j) {
    str = "." + Integer.toString(j);
    num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
    disp.setText(str);

}

public void buttonDeci(View v) {

    deciDisplay(((int) num));

}
```

Comment: What input are you providing? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: A **decimal** number is not an **integer** number. You should use **double** or **float**, instead.

Comment: Considering this input `3` so output will be `0.3`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: well its just a basic calculator, the input is a integer and in this case its outputing a double (ie. 5.0). when i test this it force closes my app , so i dont get an output right now. if i input 5, and hit the decimal button. i should then be able to input another number and get something like , 5.2

Comment: You mean you want to convert Integer to Decimal?

Comment: Like the Golem said, this won't work with Integer, as those are full numbers only.

Comment: lol i appologize for the confusion. I thought it would be easy to mimic what the decimal button on a calculator does.  im having trouble understanding how it works.

Comment: I made some code, but I'm afraid it only solves your directly asked issue, not your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like Golem said, you need to use a double or float, as Integers only have full numbers:

```
private void deciDisplay(int j) {
    str = "." + Integer.toString(j); //Or String.valueOf(j);
    num = Double.parseDouble(str);
    disp.setText(str);

}
```

Edit:

This may solve your actual problem of simply putting a dot to your TextView:

```
public void buttonDeci(View v){
    num+=".";
    disp.setText(num);
}
```

Assuming num is a String. If it's not, you somehow need an index to tell your calculator that you're behind the decimal dot now.

Comment: yeah i understood that , and i made the changes.. but when i try this. i hit the a number like 5 , then the decimal button , and it gives me .5 and then it crashes. it wont let me enter the next number

Comment: Like I said, for anything goin further you'll need to either let num be a String (I guess it's a kind of number in your code, or you couldn't simply cast it to int as in your code sample) and use parseDouble() each time you want to use it in a calculation, or implement the index. For your crashing issue, please post your LogCat output and the part of your code conatining the line which crashes your app.

Comment: You can just cast the int to a float without having to make a string out of it. float floatNumber = (float) intNumber;

Comment: I made it a String so one may easily attach new numbers at will. now: `num = "5."`, then you press 6 and go `num+="6"; disp.setText(num);`.